# _curses.error: addstr() returned ERR

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, curses, python-curses

Using Python, I am trying to write a script which will convert all typed characters into 'a' whenever you pressed space-bar. For example, i typed "python" and then space, then "python" will convert into "aaaaaa".

```
import argparse
import curses
import time

# Main Function
def main():
    screen=curses.initscr()
    curses.cbreak()
    screen.keypad(1)
    curses.echo()
    str_txt=''
    count = 0
    while True:
        s=screen.getch()
        if s != ord(' ') and s != ord('\x1b') and s != curses.KEY_BACKSPACE and s != curses.KEY_ENTER:
            str_txt += chr(int(s))
            count+=1

        if s == ord(' '):
            dim = screen.getyx()
            h = 'a'*len(str_txt)+' '
            screen.addstr(dim[0],dim[1]-count-1, h)     
            count=0
            str_txt=''
            screen.refresh()

        if s == curses.KEY_ENTER or s==10 or s==13:
            dim = screen.getyx()
            screen.move(dim[0]+1,0)
            screen.refresh()

        #if s == curses.KEY_BACKSPACE:
        #   dim = screen.getyx()
        #   screen.move(dim[0],dim[1])
        #   screen.refresh()

        if s == ord('\x1b'):
            curses.endwin()
            break

if __name__  == "__main__":
    main()
```

The above code works fine for 1st line, however, in the second line whenever i press spacebar, i am getting an error on line 22 saying "_curses.error: addstr() returned ERR"

EDITED:
When I change screen.addstr(dim[0],dim[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4BxN.png)-count-1, h) to screen.addstr(dim[0],dim[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4BxN.png)-count, h), the error is eliminated but the output is not what I want. I have attached to output for your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
if s != ord(' ') and s != ord('\x1b') and s != curses.KEY_BACKSPACE:
    str_txt += chr(int(s))
    count+=1
```

That if statement executes for the carriage return and\or newline char too I think, so I think your count is 1 over what you expected, due to the first line.

The addstr() returned ERR exception is because the cursor is being moved off screen (out of bound) due to:

```
screen.addstr(dim[0],dim[1]-count-1, h)
```

Since your count is +1 due to the carriage return (\r) at the end of your first line. The first if should check this and not increase the count. Try to add these checks `s!=curses.KEY_ENTER and s!=10 and s!=13` to the first if and see if that helps. `s!=10` will check the new line char (\n) (which may not be necessary in this case, but I am OCD). `s!=13` will check the carriage return character (\r).

Comment: It didn't work. Although it solved my other problem, so thank you.
I have updated the code with what you recommend. But the above error still exist.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint at screen.addstr(dim[0],dim[1]-count-1, h) and debug? I can't seem to install curses on python 2.7.

Comment: curses module is only for linux version and its there by default you dont have to install anything in linux. And i am using terminal, so i am not sure how to use breakpoint in the code.
I have edited the question to give you more information, if that can help

Comment: What is the output when you took out the 1 offset?

Comment: count is still 1 over what it should be after the newline character. That's why the first series of chars on every line after the first works without the -1 offset and breaks with it. Maybe you can add some print statements to echo out the count and the str_txt variable. That would help debug.

Comment: maybe the carriage return char is being detected. Can you add s!=13 (and s!=10 too, for good measure), to the first if statement?

Comment: That works. (s!=13 and s!=10) This actually works. Thanks a lot.
please update the your answer accordingly with detailed explanation.

Comment: The error is due to out-of-bounds movement (the x value is negative in the addstr call).

Answer (score 1):

There was more than one place to improve the given example.  Here is a revised version:

```
import curses
import time

# Main Function
def main():
    screen=curses.initscr()
    curses.cbreak()
    screen.keypad(1)
    curses.echo()
    screen.scrollok(1)
    str_txt=''
    count = 0
    while True:
        dim = screen.getyx()
        s=screen.getch()
        if s != ord(' ') and s != ord('\x1b') and s != curses.KEY_BACKSPACE and s != curses.KEY_ENTER and s != 10 and s != 13:
            str_txt += chr(int(s))
            count+=1

        if s == ord(' '):
            if count > 0:
                h = 'a'*len(str_txt)+' '
                screen.addstr(dim[0],dim[1]-count, h)
                count=0
                str_txt=''

        if s == curses.KEY_ENTER or s==10 or s==13:
            if count > 0:
                h = 'a'*len(str_txt)
                screen.addstr(dim[0],dim[1]-count, h)
                count=0
                str_txt=''
            screen.move(dim[0]+1,0)
            count=0
        str_txt=''

        #if s == curses.KEY_BACKSPACE:
        #   dim = screen.getyx()
        #   screen.move(dim[0],dim[1])
        #   screen.refresh()

        if s == ord('\x1b'):
            curses.endwin()
            break

if __name__  == "__main__":
    main()
```

For example:

- the screen.refresh calls are not needed, since screen.getch does that.
- no check was made to ensure that the count was nonzero
- pressing enter (or return) did not behave the "same" as space.
- the movement after enter/return moved two lines rather than one.
- the screen would not scroll at the end (partial fix in this example)